# Is it necessary to unsubscribe from a Redux store in an Angular component

Tags: angular, redux, observable

I am almost certain that i should, but i have not found any specific information on the Redux documentation. My pattern in most of my Angular components, is that i subscribe/unsubscribe to a Redux store like :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'selector',
    templateUrl: 'name.component.html'
})
export class ComponentNameComponent implements OnInit {
    private unsubscribe : Function;

    constructor(@Inject(AppStore) private store: Store<AppState>) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.unsubscribe = this.store.subscribe ( ()=>{ this.updateFromState(); });
    }
    // Is unsubscribing onDestroy necessary?
    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.unsubscribe();
    }

    this.updateFromState(){
        // ...
    }
}
```

So i would like to know if i should always unsubscribe from the Store, and what would happen if i didn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you should destroy `(unsubscribe)` all the observables within your application when they are not in use. I have no idea about `Redux store`, but I feel you should still kill your observables in `onDestroy`.

**What happens if you don't unsubscribe()?**

First time when your component is loaded `ngOnInit()` will subscribe to `store` and now again if you go back to some other component and then revisit the same component, you will have new `subscription` along with previous one (so 2 subscriptions). This `subscription` count increases as many times as you revisit the component, which will reduce the performance of your application. So safer side you should be killing the previous `subscription` before creating new one, which is usually done in `ngOnDestroy()`.

Comment: The Redux subscribe returns a function and 'Function' is a Typescript type. Not the same as RxJS Observable/Subsciption
[Redux Subscribe](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe)

Comment: Yes my bad!. Thanks for notifying that.

Comment: Your logic seems correct, and i suppose that the Observable pattern should be always used the same way, but i just wanted some hard evidence that i could not find. I will accept your answer, unless someone comes up with a specific Redux related reference. Thanks!

Comment: It's also worth to mention that there is no need to unsubscribe from short-lived observables (obviously not in the case of store). Additionally it's a good practice to use the `async` pipe as much as possible as it handles subscribing/unsubscribing automatically.

Comment: Could you please provide any reference on the async pipe information you shared? Thanks @dzejdzej

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html

> When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks.